# Ionic - Add different icons to list items made with ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Is there a way to have specific icons for each item in a list made with *ngFor*?
Will it be better to not auto generate the menu items?

app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="mainContent">
<ion-content id="side-menu" style="background-color:#7A5258;">
    <ion-list no-lines id="menu-list">
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-bookmark"></ion-icon>
            {{p.title}}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp {
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
rootPage: any = HomePage;

pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();
    });

    // ngFor menu items
    this.pages = [
        {title: 'Home', component: HomePage},
        {title: 'Bookmarks', component: BookmarksPage},
        {title: 'Help', component: HelpPage},
        {title: 'Settings', component: SettingsPage},
    ];
}

openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to the `pages` array as shown below.

**Note:** Change you `icons` as you wish.

*app.component.ts*

```
    // ngFor menu items
    this.pages = [
        {title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon: 'play'},
        {title: 'Bookmarks', component: BookmarksPage, icon: 'play'},
        {title: 'Help', component: HelpPage, icon: 'play'},
        {title: 'Settings', component: SettingsPage, icon: 'play'},
    ];
```

*app.html*

```
<ion-menu [content]="mainContent">
<ion-content id="side-menu" style="background-color:#7A5258;">
    <ion-list no-lines id="menu-list">
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
           <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" item-left></ion-icon> 
            {{p.title}}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I had a similar attempt, but ignored the pages array! Thank you Sampath.

Comment: @Sampath - I dont know if this is the right forum but what if I wanted to assign 1 of 3 possible background colors to each item generated by the *ngFor?  I was working on the same principal of including a "status" in my page array which would correspond to a custom color in my .ts file.  I'm just not sure of the syntax.  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="viewItem(item)"  style="background-color:{{item.status}}">{{item.title}}</ion-item> but that got an error.

Comment: Please open a new question for your issue @JonathanSmall